# Using subreport in crystal reports 8.5, How can we stop overlapping it with the end of the main report?

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, overlap

I've created a new report using crystal reports 8.5.
In it, I've used 3 sub reports and they are positioned in main report vertically.
My question is, How can I stop overlapping them with each other and also with the down border of the main report?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you split the section they're in into 3 sections (eg, Report Header can divide into Report Header a, Report Header b and Report Header c), and place one subreport in each, the sections will expand to fit their contents in and the subreports should no longer overlap.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight, 
Thank you so much...You've solved many of my C.R. questions so far....

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found is to do following:

1. Right click on the details page and choose "Section Expert..."
2. In the opened dialog box Sections column click on
   the Details(preferred) or other section and click on Insert button above.
3. In the newly inserted section add your new sub report.

[image]

Thanks